# Parse JSON string/array into JS objects

Tags: javascript, c#, json

So I have used JSON to serialize a list of objects from C# to send to JS. The list seems to arrive at the browser but I can't figure out how to use it correctly. It makes sense that what arrives is a string however it seems to actually be an array... I'm not sure and I can't figure out how to use it.

Here is my JS

```
var data;
function testFunc() {
    d3.select("#stuff").append("h2").text(data[0].source);   
}
```

When I send a single object the above JS prints out the value properly. Here is that C#

```
protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new testClass(66,77));
            ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("data", json);
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "id", "testFunc()", true);
        }
```

When I look at the browser's debugger I see this line below when the above is executed:

```
var data =  new Array({"target":66,"source":77});
```

This is what allows me to print the value 77 in the JS above

The annoying thing is that I want to send a list of this exact same object. So I use the following C#

```
List<TestGraph.Models.testClass> L = new List<TestGraph.Models.testClass>()
private List<testClass> fill()
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                L.Add(new testClass(i, i+1));
            }
            return L;
        }
        protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fill();
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(L);
            ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("data", json);
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "id", "testFunc()", true);
        }
```

When I use the same JS it won't print anything out however the list is getting to the JS because I see below when I look at the browser's debugger:

```
var data =  new Array([{"target":0,"source":1},{"target":1,"source":2},{"target":2,"source":3},{"target":3,"source":4},{"target":4,"source":5},{"target":5,"source":6},{"target":6,"source":7},{"target":7,"source":8},{"target":8,"source":9},{"target":9,"source":10}]);
```

So, since the list of data is in the browser how do I use it?

PS Not really necessary but here is my testClass if anyone is curious

```
public class testClass
    {
        public int target { get; set; }
        public int source { get; set; }
        public testClass(int t, int s)
        {
            target = t;
            source = s;
        }
        public testClass()
        {

        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

For those suggesting I have tried using JSON.parse(data)

I used this:

```
var data;
var data2 = JSON.parse(data);
function testFunc() {
    d3.select("#stuff").append("h2").text(data2[1].source);
}
```

**EDIT**

So when I step through the C# the line:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(L);
```

puts the following string into the json var:

```
"[{\"target\":0,\"source\":1},{\"target\":1,\"source\":2},{\"target\":2,\"source\":3},{\"target\":3,\"source\":4},{\"target\":4,\"source\":5},{\"target\":5,\"source\":6},{\"target\":6,\"source\":7},{\"target\":7,\"source\":8},{\"target\":8,\"source\":9},{\"target\":9,\"source\":10}]"
```

Then in theory when I call:

```
ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("data", json);
```

it should put the above string into the 'data' var in the js however when I do an alert on it as such:

```
var data;
function testFunc() {
    alert(data);
}
```

What appears is

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

I also tried another method in my C#:

```
protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fill();
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(L);
            Response.Write(string.Concat("<input id='data' type='hidden' value='", json, "' />"));
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "id", "testFunc()", true);
        }
```

Which required the following change to the JS

```
var field = document.getElementById('data');
var data = JSON.parse(field.value);
function testFunc() {
    alert(data);
}
```

When I try this new method I get the same as before:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

And I did a second test on the field var from the method above and got

```
[object HTMLInputElement]
```

Comment: please add your sample json

Comment: `var data =  new Array([{"target":0,"source":1},{"target":1,"source":2},{"target":2,"source":3},{"target":3,"source":4},{"target":4,"source":5},{"target":5,"source":6},{"target":6,"source":7},{"target":7,"source":8},{"target":8,"source":9},{"target":9,"source":10}]);` is an Array of Objects within another pointless Array, as `var ary = []` is the same as `var ary = new Array()`.

Comment: @PHPglue I can see that but I didn't write that. It's just there in my browser debugger. That's what is sent to the browser.

Comment: then are you sure in **data** there was json? Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/hjsunL9g/

Comment: @m.antkowicz Well, I'm not positive to tell you the truth. That big long string is where it starts "var data = new Array([{"target..." is just what I see in the browser. As described above when I send a single object I can just use data[0].source to access that objects members... so I guess data isn't receiving a JSON string. I don't really know how ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration really works.

Comment: then do a simple test - printout (or alert or anything) **data** just before parsing it - the JSON is a string in definition so if nothing will appear then your problem is on C# side and generating the json from the list

Answer (score 2):

just use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

for example:

```
    var parsed = JSON.parse('[{"target":0,"source":1},{"target":1,"source":2},{"target":2,"source":3},{"target":3,"source":4},{"target":4,"source":5},{"target":5,"source":6},{"target":6,"source":7},{"target":7,"source":8},{"target":8,"source":9},{"target":9,"source":10}]');
    console.log(parsed[1].target);
```